# When I try to put a class into a header I get the error of member not found when I compile with strings in the class

Tags: c++, header

Here is the code:

Classes.h

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H
// Team Class
class Team {
public: 
    string title, initials;
};
// End

// Player Class
class Player {
public:
    int skill, cost;
    string name;
};
// End

// Coach Class
class Coach {
    int cash, cost, players;
public:
    string name;
    void set_values (int, int);
    int total (void) {return (cash - cost);};
};
// End
#endif
```

Classes.cpp

```
#include "Classes.h"
// Set Total Cash for Coach
void Coach::set_values (int a, int b) {
    cash = a;
    cost = b;
}
// End
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "classes.h"
```

---

When I compile it does not find the initials member or the name members, meaning the strings. Why and how can I fix this.

I.E

```
main.cpp:22: error: ‘class Player’ has no member named ‘name’
main.cpp:28: error: ‘class Coach’ has no member named ‘name’
main.cpp:29: error: ‘class Coach’ has no member named ‘name’
main.cpp:30: error: ‘class Player’ has no member named ‘name’
main.cpp:35: error: ‘class Team’ has no member named ‘title’
main.cpp:36: error: ‘class Team’ has no member named ‘title’
main.cpp:38: error: ‘class Team’ has no member named ‘initials’
main.cpp:39: error: ‘class Team’ has no member named ‘initials’
main.cpp:40: error: ‘class Player’ has no member named ‘name’
main.cpp:40: error: ‘class Team’ has no member named ‘title’
main.cpp:41: error: ‘class Team’ has no member named ‘initials’
main.cpp:41: error: ‘class Player’ has no member named ‘name’
main.cpp:41: error: ‘class Coach’ has no member named ‘name’
```

Or
In file included from main.cpp:9:

```
classes.h:7: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
classes.h:15: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
classes.h:23: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
```

Please help! I am a novice, so it is probably something I either can't do or a simple fix.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `#include <string>` in the `classes.h` file and change `string` variable declarations to `std::string`.
For example:

```
class Team {
public: 
std::string title, initials;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std::string` the full qualification and also `#include <string>` to your header file.